# Recursion with accumulators that are not reversed - is it possible?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, recursion, primes

I've been playing with Haskell a fair amount lately, and I came up with this function to find the *n*th prime:

```
nthPrime 1 = 2
nthPrime 2 = 3
nthPrime n = aux [2, 3] 3 5 n
  where
    aux knownPrimes currentNth suspect soughtNth =
      let currentIsPrime = foldl (\l n -> l && suspect `mod` n /= 0) 
                                 True knownPrimes
      in case (currentIsPrime, soughtNth == currentNth) of
        (True, True) -> suspect
        (True, False) -> aux (suspect:knownPrimes) (currentNth + 1) 
                             (suspect + 2) soughtNth
        _ -> aux knownPrimes currentNth (suspect + 2) soughtNth
```

My question is, is there a way to have an accumulative parameter (in this case `knownPrimes`) that is not reversed (as occurs when passing `(suspect:knownPrimes)`)?

I have tried using `knownPrimes ++ [suspect]` but this seems inefficient as well.

My hope is that if I can pass the known primes in order then I can shortcut some of the primality checks further.

Comment: There's no way I can imagine. There are only 3 fast operation on haskell's list: prepend, get head, remove head. Everything else is slow. Perhaps you need to change the algorithm

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Is there another potential abstract data type I could use?

Comment: Hi - yes there are efficient data structures for this: [difference Lists](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Difference_list) and the [one implementation I could find](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dlist-0.7.1/docs/Data-DList.html)

Comment: Difference lists will be terrible for this since the accumulating parameter is being frequently examined by foldl.

Comment: I tried replacing list with a [queue](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dequeue-0.1.5). Initial benchmarks showed that using list append (knownPrimes ++ [suspect]) gave slightly better performance than the queue, and both were about twice as fast as prepend (knownPrimes : suspect). I suspect that laziness makes the append basically free since the entire list is examined in each iteration anyways.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson yes this is of course true - I was not answering the question but the last comment from mjgyp3 and did not look at the question to closely

Comment: A great example of a question from someone who has put in a lot of effort into their problem, and has a very thoughtful question about methodology, brining to light sound advice about lazy production. Well done.

Comment: http://lpaste.net/113402 - an idiomatic re-write of your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Haskell, if you are using an accumulator to build a list, but end up having to reverse it, it is often the case that it is better to drop the accumulator and instead produce the list *lazily* as the result of your computation.

If you apply this kind of thinking to searching for primes, and take full advantage of laziness, you end up with a well-known technique of producing an *infinite* list of all the primes. If we refactor your code as little as possible to use this technique, we get something like:

```
allPrimes = [2, 3] ++ aux 5
  where
    aux suspect =
      let currentIsPrime = foldl (\l n -> l && suspect `mod` n /= 0) True
                               $ takeWhile (\n -> n*n <= suspect) allPrimes
      in case currentIsPrime of
        True -> suspect : aux (suspect + 2)
        False -> aux (suspect + 2)

nthPrime n = allPrimes !! (n-1)
```

I have removed now unnecessary parameters and changed the code from accumulating into lazily producing, and to use its own result as the source of prime divisors to test (this is called "tying the knot").  Other than that, the only change here is to add a `takeWhile` check: since the list we are testing divisors from is defined in terms of itself, and is infinite to boot, we need to know where on the list to *stop* checking for divisors so that we don't get a truly infinite recursion.

Apart from this, there is an inefficiency in this code:

```
foldl (\l n -> l && suspect `mod` n /= 0) True
```

is not a good way for checking whether there are no divisors in a list, because *as written*, it won't *stop* once a divisor has been found, even though `&&` itself is shortcutting (stopping as soon as its first argument is found to be `False`).

To allow proper shortcutting, a `foldr` could be used instead:

```
foldr (\n r -> suspect `mod` n /= 0 && r) True
```

Or, even better, use the predefined function `all`:

```
all (\n -> suspect `mod` n /= 0)
```

#### Using my remarks

This is how it would look like if you use `all` and refactor it a bit:

```
allPrimes :: [Integer]
allPrimes = 2 : 3 : aux 5
  where
    aux suspect 
      | currentIsPrime = suspect : nextPrimes
      | otherwise      = nextPrimes
      where
          currentIsPrime =
            all (\n -> suspect `mod` n /= 0)
            $ takeWhile (\n -> n*n <= suspect) allPrimes
          nextPrimes = aux (suspect + 2) 

nthPrime :: Int -> Integer
nthPrime n = allPrimes !! (n-1)
```

Comment: +1 - great answer - maybe you can condense all your remarks in a final version? (using `foldr`, `all`)

Comment: I added a version using your ideas/remarks - I hope you don't mind - feel free to change/remove/revoke it

Comment: @CarstenKönig No problem at all! (Although I had some tiny changes to the intro.)

Comment: actually, `foldl (\l n -> rem suspect n /= 0 && l) True` *is* shortcutting, and will test smaller primes first (significant algorithmic advantage) when called with primes list in *reversed* order.

Comment: @WillNess Hm OK `foldl` with `(&&)` can be shortcutting in that in avoids performing further actual division tests, but on the other hand not shortcutting in that it still keeps traversing the spine of the list.